# Issue with drawmapscale from basemap

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

when I tried [this drawmapscale example](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#drawmapscale) I got the exact results from there:

[map scale with correct size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oenqo.png)

but when I run the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=-50,lon_0=180,lat_0=-90,
        resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightblue')
m.drawmapscale(lon=0,lat=-60,lon0=180,lat0=-90,length=1000)
plt.show()
```

I have a map scale with wrong format like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qttd.png)

Could anyone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here?
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the figure size bigger, then plot, and get a map with better scale bar.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-50, \
            lon_0=180, lat_0=-90, resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='white', lake_color='aqua')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightblue')
m.drawmapscale(lon=0, lat=-60, lon0=180, lat0=-90, length=1000)

plt.show()
```

The resulting map:

[image]

Is this what you want?